# Enable BOSH services in XMPP IOS framework (XMPPFramework) to create chat based app

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I have implemented Chat based application. I can able to do many functionality with https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework library. It is very good library. But after some days my server side guys included bash services in server. My server side guys implementing xmpp using Strophe.js. And they are using following code to enable BOSH service while connecting.

```
BOSH_SERVICE = "http://host.com:5280/http-bind";
new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
```

Now they told me enable BASH service in IOS side also. Now I can not connect to that server. 
How to include BOSH service in robbiehanson xmpp IOS library (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)?

Answer (score 3):

The iOS xmppFramework does not currently offer support for BOSH. Here's a confirmation:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/6#issuecomment-54085037

But, your iOS client can still login to the server via the socket connection and your web client can use BOSH. That's your alternative and it should work well.

If you really want to create your own iOS BOSH implementation, look into `XMPPTransports` as a starting point.

Happy coding :)